# Python: How to atomically hardlink files for deduplication?

Tags: python

I have an application which deduplicates the contents of two directories using hardlinks. I'd like to protect this code from crashes, such that a traceback would never result in loss of data.

Currently, the code looks something like this:

```
import os
import tempfile

for path_a, path_b in paths_to_dedupe:
    handle, tmp = tempfile.mkstemp(dir=os.path.dirname(path_a))
    handle.close()
    os.remove(tmp)
    os.link(path_a, tmp)
    os.rename(tmp, path_b)
```

The problem with this code is the call to os.remove() -- this makes the call to mkstemp no longer entirely safe (because another tempfile of the same name could be created, however unlikely).

Is there a safer way to do this?

I considered copying and modifying `tempfile._mkstemp_inner()` so it runs `_os.link` rather than `_os.open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method will be to loop until the `os.link` succeeds:

```
while True:
    handle, tmp = tempfile.mkstemp(…)
    os.close(handle)
    os.remove(tmp)
    try:
        os.link(path_a, tmp)
    except OSError as e:
       if e.errno == 17: # file exists
          continue
       raise
    break
```

And in this case, there's no real benefit to using `tempfile` (ie, because you don't need to end up with an open file), so you might as well do it yourself:

```
while True:
    tmp = path_b + "-temp-%s" %(os.urandom(8).encode("hex"), )
    try:
        os.link(path_a, tmp)
    except OSError as e:
       if e.errno == 17: # file exists
          continue
       raise
    break
```

And, of course, you'll want to throw a `try/finally` around that whole thing to make sure you don't accidentally leave the temp file lying around if you explode before moving it into place :)

Comment: I really like os.urandom(8).encode('hex') -- very nice.